# Is it possible to load variable fonts and manipulate them with javascript?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

With Chrome 62, variable fonts are now enabled by default. [Demos exist](http://www.axis-praxis.org/) that show the ability to manipulate the fonts if they are installed in the browser's operating system, but I am unable to do the same manipulations if they are loaded from within the page.

For example, the following CSS is able to load the '[Decovar](https://github.com/TypeNetwork/fb-Decovar)' font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Decovar';
  src: url('//rawgit.com/TypeNetwork/fb-Decovar/master/fonts/DecovarAlpha-
VF.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and the font renders correctly in the page. however, setting the `fontWeight` to values that *aren't* multiples of `100`, which should show continuous weight changes, just show the old quantized weights (ie, 300, 400, 500, etc...). setting the 'fontVariationSettings' css style rule does nothing.

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/Spongman/pen/KXEBZb) that demonstrates this.

Is there something I'm missing here? Or are variable fonts limited to natively installed fonts?

Answer (score 1):

When I download Decovar and drag it onto that axis-praxis.org page, it reveals that the property for Weight is named WMX2. Setting that variation works for me.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let p = document.querySelector('p');

input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  p.style.fontVariationSettings = `'WMX2' ${input.value}`
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Decovar";
  src: url("https://rawgit.com/TypeNetwork/fb-Decovar/master/fonts/DecovarAlpha-VF.ttf") format("truetype");
}

p {
  font-family: "Decovar";
}
```

```html
<input type=range min=0 max=1000>
<p>hamburgefonstiv
```